# Searching SQL Server database in C# with binary search or parallel programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database with very large records inside the table. And I'm trying to build an ASP.NET website using C# to search inside my SQL Server database, and the result will be displayed in a gridview. The database is already have Primary Key in column `NIM`.
This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class SearchPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GILANG-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Mahasiswa;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "select * from Mahasiswa where (NIM like '%' + @search + '%')";
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(str, cnn);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    cnn.Open();
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "NIM");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cnn.Close();
}
}
```

The code above can run properly. But I'm curious of two things, how can I use binary search method to search that database? And is it possible to use a parallel code to search that database?
I already did some research and experiments, but doesn't work. Maybe the masters here can help. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> An index can be created in a table to find data more quickly
>   and efficiently.
>
> The users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up
>   searches/queries.
>
> Note: Updating a table with indexes takes more time than updating a
>   table without (because the indexes also need an update). So you should
>   only create indexes on columns (and tables) that will be frequently
>   searched against.

Here is an the [Article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp). You can search in the web for a lot of articles about SQL Indexes.

If you want article in dept for SQL indexes and how they work [see this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/) !

> What kind of data structure is an index?
>
> B- trees are the most commonly used data structures for indexes. The
>   reason B- trees are the most popular data structure for indexes is due
>   to the fact that they are time efficient – because look-ups,
>   deletions, and insertions can all be done in **logarithmic time**. And,
>   another major reason B- trees are more commonly used is because the
>   data that is stored inside the B- tree can be sorted. The RDBMS
>   typically determines which data structure is actually used for an
>   index. But, in some scenarios with certain RDBMS’s, you can actually
>   specify which data structure you want your database to use when you
>   create the index itself.

Like you see in the article here we have the same complexity as binary search-> logarthmic time.

**EDIT**: Like learningNew said if you use LIKE the indexes will not help, so you need to change LIKE to SQL Contains and [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) for this column.

Comment: the query is using wild card in beginning as well as end so there is very less possibilty of using index , it still may perform an index scan on a full/partial range of the index.So performance is very less likely to improve.

Comment: @learningNew you are right I don't see that. In this case he should not use Like and use Sql Contains in this case the indexes will be used.